# Private Key Format

Tags: java, cryptography, java-security

I have been provided private key for my site in a mail.Which extension I should use to save the file? Is it .pem or .key? I have a certificate in .crt format and need to generate ceritificate signed SAML assertion using this private key in JAVA. I am not sure how to read the private key provided in the mail . The key looks like

> ```
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAtu7fdfdsfsdfsdfsd15gBG4+31GV7mF0MzGIjingYDb   
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> ```

Comment: The extension is not important. Use whatever you feel is appropriate. `.jpg` is probably not a good idea, but I think `.privatekey` is free. An application doesn't need to know the extension, because its format is included in the header.

Comment: While it is true that the file extension does not programatically affect how a file is read due to the file header, you will almost always see private keys stored in a `.key` file.